# Will this example code for g_cond_wait() lead to undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, multithreading, glib

This is an example from the Glib docs for `g_cond_wait()`:

```
gpointer current_data = NULL;
GMutex data_mutex;
GCond data_cond;

void push_data (gpointer data)
{
  g_mutex_lock (&data_mutex); // (3)
  current_data = data;
  g_cond_signal (&data_cond);
  g_mutex_unlock (&data_mutex); // (4)
}

gpointer pop_data (void)
{
  gpointer data;

  g_mutex_lock (&data_mutex); // (1)
  while (!current_data)
    g_cond_wait (&data_cond, &data_mutex); // (2)
  data = current_data;
  current_data = NULL;
  g_mutex_unlock (&data_mutex); // (5)

  return data;
}
```

Let's now go through this:

- First thread calls `pop_data()`, `data_mutex` is locked (1)
- `g_cond_wait()` is called, `data_mutex` is unlocked (2), first thread is waiting
- Second thread calls `push_data()`, `data_mutex` is locked (3)
- Second thread signals the first one that the wait condition is satisfied, unlocks `data_mutex` (4)
- First thread wakes up, exits from `g_cond_wait()` and unlocks `data_mutex` again (5)

The docs say that unlocking a non-locked mutex is undefined. Does this mean the example contains a bug? Or will `g_cond_wait()` lock the mutex before exiting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The docs say that unlocking a non-locked mutex is undefined. Does this
>   mean the example contains a bug? Or will g_cond_wait() lock the mutex
>   before exiting?

There's no bug here. There's no unlocking of a mutex which wasn't locked in the code. `g_cond_wait()` will lock the mutex when it returns.

Thread1 calls `g_cond_wait()` with mutex locked and `g_cond_wait()` atomically unlocks the mutex and waits on the condition. After this, thread2 locks the mutex and performs the operation, then *signals* to thread1 which is waiting in `g_cond_wait()`. But thread1 can't continue as the mutex is still not available (thread2 is yet to unlock it). So after the call `g_mutex_unlock()` in thread2 unlocks it, `g_cond_wait()` in thread1 locks the mutex and the call returns.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the mutex is locked again after the wait. From the glib docs for [g_cond_wait()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Threads.html#g-cond-wait):

> When this function returns, mutex is locked again and owned by the
>   calling thread.

Comment: What about *The docs say that unlocking a non-locked mutex is undefined. Does this mean the example contains a bug?*

Comment: @BlueMoon - because `g_cond_wait` locks the mutex when it returns, there is no path that leads to unlocking a non-locked mutex.

Comment: @mtrw - Sorry, no idea how I missed that bit while reading the docs. Thanks!